# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+n)^{-z}} \ $, $ z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm studying the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+n)^{-z}}$$

If $z = x+iy$, what is the behaviour of the series for $-1<x<0 \ $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series is the Riemann zeta function thinly disguised:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+n)^{-z}} = \zeta(-z)-1.$$

Comment: I don't know your function, I want to do direct calculations

Comment: @WLOG, the fact that this is essentially the Riemann-Euler zeta function suggests that naive, direct computations may be surprisingly unfruitful (without luck/cleverness). Rather, there are many things already known, for 150+ years, some by relatively elementary means, some much less elementary, but few "straightforward".